# How to transfer php code from javascript to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, transfer

So I create text(php) editor and I want to execute PHP code without refreshing page.
Now I use cookies to transfer code from javascript(which grab editor content). 
Then color box opens and PHP file write cookie content to file, which is included.
And there is question:

Is there any other way to transfer PHP code from javascipt to PHP? Or any other way to execute PHP code? I know there is a AJAX, but I want to transfer a larger data including special characters(",',],[,$ etc.), that occur in PHP.

Yes, I use it only on localhost for education purpose only :)
Sorry for my english, I hope you understand me.

Comment: Sure hoping you have set some pretty good authentication on that code, sounds like a massive hole in the server security otherwise..

Comment: "Yes, I use it only on localhost :)" It is for education purpose only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is suitable for sending large amounts of code. Take a look at [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Special characters pass through POST-request unchanged.

Make sure you set php setting `magic_quotes_gpc` to `off`, as this option tells PHP to escape any special character with backslash.

Comment: Now i use ` if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $_COOKIE[''] = stripslashes($_COOKIE['']);    
}`

Comment: Anyway better use AJAX request. But if you are comfortable with what you already have - no need to change it.

Comment: COOKIE size is limited for only 4096 bytes ... I think ... So this is not the best way. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use AJAX, only with POST, this time.
Try something like:

```
<script>
code = '<? echo "Hi"; ?>'
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST","http://foo.com/bar.php";
ajax.send("code="+code+"&foo=bar")
</script>
```

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax to learn more about Ajax.