# Best mysql data type for storing php code?

Tags: php, mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I want to store php code in Mysql database and I am wondering which data type I can use. I will store large amount of data with special characters like ",*,$ etc.

So which mysql data tpye I can use?

//Why? See [My other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010506/how-to-transfer-php-code-from-javascript-to-php)

Comment: The best MySQL data type for PHP code is `CHAR(0)`. :-/

Comment: Well, you looked at [Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html) and decided on what? -1 for no apparent research.

Comment: why you want to store php code in mysql?

Comment: special characters don't have any influence on the chosen datatype. use proper escaping and you should be set.

Comment: Why? See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010506/how-to-transfer-php-code-from-javascript-to-php) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXT .. but if you ever want to use eval(), rethink about storing code in db..

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`TEXT` column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), if there is to be more than just a few characters of code stored.